# Parse Bitnami Server is not showing database / data in the dashboard of parse powered by Bitnami

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, bitnami

hello I am working on Parse to AWS migration. I had installed MongoDB on EC2-Instance and Bitnami Parse Server on other EC2-Instance. And Migrated some dummy data from parse app to EC2-Instance of MongoDB.

but when I open

```
> http://ec2-**-***-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com/apps
```

it show this..[image]

and when i clik on "My Bitnami Parse API" it show a blank page...[image]

this is my server.js file code :

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
// Specify the connection string for your mongodb database
// and the location to your Parse cloud code
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "mongodb://dbuser:Pass@**.***.***.***:27017/dbname",
    cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
    appId: *******************************",
    masterKey: "***********************************",
    fileKey: "***********************************",
    serverURL: 'http://ec2-**-***-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/parse'
});
// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

var port = 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port);
});

//Parse Dashboard
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    apps: [
        {
            appName: "My Bitnami Parse API",
            appId: "***********************************",
            masterKey: "***********************************",
            fileKey: "***********************************",
            production: true,
            serverURL: 'http://ec2-**-***-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/parse'
        }
    ]
});

var allowInsecureHTTP = true;

// Serve the Parse Dashboard on the /parsedashboard URL prefix
app.use('/', dashboard);

var portdash = 4040;
app.listen(portdash, function() {
    console.log('parse-dashboard running on port ' + portdash);
});
```

please tell me what I have done wrong that my database is not showing data here.

I already checked my MongoDB database it has the migrated data in it.

Comment: Are your port 27017 4040 1337 open in Sec group?

Comment: In Which Instance You Are Referring to Mongo or Parse Server.

Comment: Both the instance? Try one thing to check if this is port issue open all Traffic in the security groups for both instances and then check if it works. So if it works then it it port issue and if not then this is a application issue

Comment: I tried to allow all type of traffic from Anywhere but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok then there is some application issue

Comment: what it can be.? can you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are perceiving is a Parse Dashboard which is unable to connect to your new MongoDB database. 
First of all, did you check that, in this line, the MongoDB host specified (Together with the credentials) is correct?

`databaseURI: "mongodb://dbuser:Pass@**.***.***.***:27017/dbname"`

Second of all, as already specified here, you have to allow connections to mongoDB incoming from your parse machine towards your MongoDB database, which is achieved in AWS through Security Groups.

You can check if those two things are alright via executing this in your parse machine:

`/opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo -udbuser -pPass --host mongoDBHost dbname`

where `dbuser`, `Pass`, `dbname` and `mongoDBHost` should be changed by the actual values. After executing that, you should get something like:

`bitnami@ip-172-31-36-170:~$ mongo -uroot -pXXXX --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 bitnami_parse
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse
>`

If, instead, you got something like:

`bitnami@ip-172-31-36-170:~$ mongo -uroot -pXXXX --host 128.0.0.1 --port 27017 bitnami_parse
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
connecting to: 128.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse
2016-09-19T13:30:28.456+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 128.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-09-19T13:30:28.457+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 128.0.0.1:27017 (128.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed`

Then, it would mean that the previous steps must be rechecked.

Finally, did you migrate all the data in the default MongoDB database to the new one?

Let me know if none of this worked; it would be quite weird though.

Good luck! :)

PS: Remember that we're running that server.js script with `forever` so as to ensure it's being run all the time. If you perform changes to it you must execute `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart parse` in order to get those changes taken into account. In case issues arise (because of bad formatting... etc), check `forever` logs.

Comment: When I ran  /opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo -qxyzdbuser -12345 --host 62.321.123.123 qxyzdb  >> then i get the error >>
Error parsing command line: unknown option -q
try '/opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo.bin --help' for more information >>

Comment: That is normal! You didn't specify the command correctly:
try this: 
`/opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo -uqxyzdbuser -p12345 --host 62.321.123.123 qxyzdb`
You got to prepend a `-u` and a `-p` flags for specifying the user and password.

Comment: I get the following output ` root@ip-*-*-*-5:/home/bitnami# /opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo -udbuser -p12345 --host 34.27.01.123 mydb
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
connecting to: 34.27.01.123:27017/mydb
2016-09-22T08:26:35.355+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 34.27.01.123:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-09-22T08:26:35.357+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 34.27.01.123:27017 (34.27.01.123), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed `

Comment: That's it. You can not connect to the database. Check the security groups for the mongoDB server and whether or not it's currently allowing remote connections. Retry this until it works (you'd get a shell).

Comment: Thank you. Now it works fine. can you tell me how to start mongoDB service for forever. because when I start the service using command 'mongod' it stops automatically after some time.

Comment: There are several ways of achieving that. I would use `sudo npm install -g forever && forever mongod`.